# Пытаюсь разобраться с JSONCPP выводит ошибки

Tags: c++, c, json

При попытке парсинга вылетают ошибки, формат json:

```
{"edges":[{"src":"name0","dest":"name1","delay":"5"},{"src":"name2","dest":"name0","delay":"6"},{"src":"name0","dest":"name4","delay":"6"},{"src":"name2","dest":"name3","delay":"8"},{"src":"name1","dest":"name5","delay":"7"},{"src":"name1","dest":"name5","delay":"7"},{"src":"name2","dest":"name4","delay":"4"},{"src":"name2","dest":"name4","delay":"4"},{"src":"name4","dest":"name6","delay":"6"},{"src":"name4","dest":"name6","delay":"6"}]}
```

Код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "jsoncpp-master/include/json/json.h"
#include "jsoncpp-master/include/json/value.h"
#include "jsoncpp-master/include/json/writer.h"
#include "jsoncpp-master/include/json/config.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace Json;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in("2.json");
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value obj;
    reader.parse(in,obj);
    const Json::Value& edges=obj["edges"];
    for (int i=0; i< edges.size(); i++) {
        cout << "src : "<< edges[i]["scr"].asString()<<" ";
        cout << "dest : "<< edges[i]["dest"].asString()<<" ";
        cout << "delay  : "<< edges[i]["delay"].asString()<<endl<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
Scanning dependencies of target ParserJSON
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ParserJSON.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\Anvar\CLionProjects\ParserJSON\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Anvar\CLionProjects\ParserJSON\main.cpp:16:18: warning: 'Json::Reader::Reader()' is deprecated: Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     Json::Reader reader;
                  ^~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Anvar\CLionProjects\ParserJSON\jsoncpp-master/include/json/json.h:11,
                 from C:\Users\Anvar\CLionProjects\ParserJSON\main.cpp:3:
C:\Users\Anvar\CLionProjects\ParserJSON\jsoncpp-master/include/json/reader.h:56:3: note: declared here
   Reader();
   ^~~~~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable ParserJSON.exe
CMakeFiles\ParserJSON.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Json::Reader::Reader()'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Json::Reader::parse(std::istream&, Json::Value&, bool)'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*)'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `Json::Value::size() const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](int) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](int) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](int) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*) const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString[abi:cxx11]() const'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
C:/Users/Anvar/CLionProjects/ParserJSON/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\ParserJSON.dir\build.make:96: ParserJSON.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/ParserJSON.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/ParserJSON.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: ParserJSON] Error 2
```

Comment: У вас не подключена библиотека jsoncpp. Покажите свой CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но у меня складывается подозрение, что Вы скачали с GitHub'а исходный код JsonCpp (jsoncpp-master в include), распаковали его и начали пользоваться. Вы двигаетесь в верном направлении, но пропустили пару шагов. Вам необходимо собрать вручную, либо установить одним из возможных способов библиотеку JsonCpp:

- вариант 1: из исходного кода (тем более, Вы его уже скачали)
- вариант 2: используя package manager: vcpkg, conan

Затем открываете проект, и редактируете Ваш cmake-файл:

```
find_package(JsonCpp REQUIRED)

// add_executable(...)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_LIBRARIES})
```

В случае использования Conan'а:

Создаете файл (conanfile.txt) с следующим содержимым в корневом каталоге проекта:

```
[requires]
jsoncpp/1.8.4@theirix/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

Создаете директорию, например, build. Переходите в нее. Структура проекта следующая (для наглядности):

```
.
├── CMakeFiles.txt
├── build
├── conanfile.txt
├── include
└── src
```

Выполните команду `conan install ..`

Возвращаемся к cmake-файлу. В начало добавляем следующие строки:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanmoduleinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
```

Остальное, аналогично вышеприведенному, только теперь используем CONAN, например:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

станет:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92934/discussion-on-answer-by-isnullxbh----jsoncpp--).

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Parser)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Parser main.cpp)

find_package(JsonCpp REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${JsonCpp_LIBRARIES})

add_subdirectory(libs/jsoncpp-master)
```

Comment: @isnullxbh Добавил все как вы указали